# Evaluation of integral $\int_{S^2} \frac{dS}{((x-a)^2 +y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}$, where $a>1$ and $S$ is the unit sphere.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I want to evaluate$$\int_{S^2} \frac{dS}{((x-a)^2 +y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}$$
where $a >1$ and $S$ is the unit sphere.

I'm not sure how to do this using only multivariable calculus techniques. My only idea was to use the fact that the function $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}$ is harmonic away from the origin and use the mean value formula.

Comment: Without having done any calculation: Maybe it will help that the denominator is constant on spheres centered at $(a,0,0)$. Calculate the intersection of these spheres with $S^2$. Then the integral will be an $x$-integral from $a-1$ to $a+1$ over the intersections which are circles (of radii depending on $x$) parallel to the y-z-plane.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a few symmetry conditions to make our lives easier. Note that your proposed integral is equivalent to

$$\iint_{(x+a)^2+y^2+z^2=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\:dS = \iint_{(x+a)^2+y^2+z^2=1} \frac{(x+a,y,z)\cdot(x+a,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\:dS$$

Thus we can use the divergence theorem

$$= \iint_{(x+a)^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1} \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}-\frac{ax}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\:dV$$

In spherical coordinates centered around the $x$ axis, the boundary can be rewritten as

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+a^2-1 = 0 \implies \rho^2+2a\rho\cos\phi + a^2-1 = 0$$

The best way to set up the integral is with $\phi$ first like so:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{a-1}^{a+1} \int_{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-a^2}{2a\rho}-\frac{\rho}{2a}\right)}^\pi 2\rho\sin\phi - a\cos\phi\sin\phi \:d\phi\:d\rho\:d\theta$$

$$ = 2\pi\int_{a-1}^{a+1} 2\rho + \frac{5-3a^2}{4a} - \frac{9\rho^2}{8a} -\frac{(1-a^2)^2}{8a\rho^2}\:d\rho$$

$$= 2\pi \left[4a + \frac{5-3a^2}{2a}-\frac{3}{8a}(6a^2+2) - \frac{a^2-1}{4a}\right] = \frac{4\pi}{a}$$

where you can see the answer was more easily retrieved by the Mean Value Property of harmonic functions (i.e. $\int_{S^2} f = 4\pi f(0)$ due to the symmetries in the problem), but this is a purely multivariable calculus integration way of proving the result without resorting to PDEs.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't there be a $\cos\theta$ term in the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+a^2-1=0$? Also, wouldn't the $\phi$ term in the $x$-coordinate be $\sin \phi$ instead of $\cos\phi$?

Comment: @Bernardo this calculation would be a nightmare if we used standard spherical coordinates. It is centered off the $x$ axis this time, not the $z$